# Time complexity for Insertion and deletion of elements from an ordered list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

Is the time complexity for both operations equal to O(log n)?
Remeber: the list is ordered, always ordered, and not double linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both insertion and deletion in an ordered linked list is **`O(n)`** - since you first **need to find what you want to delete/add** [in deletion find the relevant node, and in insert - find the correct location of it] - which is `O(n)` - even if the list is ordered, because you need to get to this place while iterating from the head.

An efficient special type of list that allows fast insertion, deletion and look up is called a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), and it uses more nodes to iterate quickly between non adjacent nodes

Comment: Wow. Search time of O(log n) means that every operation of deletion and insertion is making in O(log n)+O(n). Is it right?

Comment: @Mariano: I did not understand the question. All search/insert/delete ops on a linked list are `O(n)`, is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, no this was clear. I was asking confirmation for insertion/deletion time for a skip list.

Comment: Oh, skip lists allow O(logn) insertion,deletion and search!

Comment: As I read on William Pugh paper about Skip List: "Binary trees can be used for representing abstract data like dictionaries. They works well when the elements are inserted in a random order."
A this point, I need a structure that insert *always*, a single element inside the list, and I can't never predict something about this element, so the insertion is pratically random.
In this case, could I use a Binary trees at place of Skip list?